# Weird value when I declare a string in C

Tags: c, string

I want to declare a string that will hold 4 chars

```
char st[4];
memcpy(st,"test",4);
```

but when I print st ... I have "test" and some other symbols printed after it - what is wrong in that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C strings, like the `"test"` string literal, are NUL-terminated, meaning the last character is '\0':

```
{'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'}
```

You would need to use `st[5]`, and copy 5 characters, to have room for (and include) the NUL.  As is, you're not including it in the copy.  So aftewards, `st` looks like:

```
{'t', 'e', 's', 't', X, X, X ... '\0'}
```

When you print, C keeps reading gibberish values that are coincidentally in memory (X'es above) until it finds a NUL.

The best solution is to eliminate `memcpy`, and let the compiler figure out the size from your initialization:

```
char st[] = "test";
```

`sizeof(st)` will now be 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use `memcpy()`, you have to copy the terminating null-byte as well:

```
char st[5];
memcpy(st, "test", 5);
```

remember, in memory `"test"` looks like that:

```
74 65 73 74 00
t  e  s  t  \0
```

that's why you have to copy 5 bytes.

If you don't copy the null byte, functions that work on null terminated strings, such as `printf()`, will read the memory until they reach some random null-byte...

Answer (score 2):

If for some weird reason want to keep your code as is, do the following:

```
char st[4];
memcpy(st,"test",4);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   printf("%c",st[i]);
```

Now it will print ok. But read the other answers to see that your programming is not ok.